# Flatlist not rendering with webservice json

Tags: php, mysql, reactjs, react-native

I‘m having this issue and I can't find a good answer (yes, already googled this **** issue)

My flatlist is not rendering with my new webservice response, getting this from WS:

```
[{"0": "1", "1": "Nescafé clásico", "2": "De la familia Nescafé", "3": "76.00", "4": "1", "Descripcion": "De la familia Nescafé", "Id": "1", "Nombre": "Nescafé clásico", "PrecioEstimado": "76.00", "Status": "1"}, {"0": "2", "1": "Coca Cola 600ml", "2": "Coca Cola en botella de plástico en presentación de 600ml", "3": "18.00", "4": "1", "Descripcion": "Coca Cola en botella de plástico en presentación de 600ml", "Id": "2", "Nombre": "Coca Cola 600ml", "PrecioEstimado": "18.00", "Status": "1"}...]
```

(3 dots means more data)

And this is my code:

```
getData() {
  fetch('https://...com/demo/Feed/getFeedProducts.php')
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((json) => {
    console.log(json);
    return json;
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
  });
}
```

`<FlatList data={this.getData()} renderItem={({item}) => (...)/>`

Is not problem from my item, I was loading a local JSON, like this:

```
getData() {
       return [{key: '1',name: 'Nescafé Clásico 120g',description: 'Nescafé',thumb:'https://siman.vtexassets.com/arquivos/ids/931095/102876460_1.jpgv=63739670031313000',price: '$76.00 mxn',
         },
         {
           key: '2',
           name: 'Coca Cola 600ml',
           description: 'Coca Cola',
           thumb: 'https://www.sixtogo.com.mx/media/catalog/product/1/2/12831_2.jpg',
           price: '$18.00 mxn',
         },
         {
           key: '3',
           name: 'Frijoles la Costeña en lata 150g',
           description: 'La Costeña',
           thumb: 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0080/1076/0255/products/039_1024x1024.jpg?v=1559773999',
           price: '$19.00 mxn',
         },
         {
           key: '4',
           name: 'Cerveza Pacifico',
           description: 'Pacifico',
           thumb: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/cervezasiempre.images-for-emails/Catalog/pacifico_lata%20(1).jpg',
           price: '$24.00 mxn',
         },
       ]
    }
```

Do i have to do something else to load this json?!
Please help :(

Comment: The return value of [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) is a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) rather than just the object itself.

Answer (score 0):

The return " return json; "  on getData() doesn't work for this .
the solution is to create/init a State or a Variable outside of this fucntion and Push the fetched value inside  : like this maybe help you

if you us a class component :

```
constructor(props){
super(props)
 this.state = {
    data : null ;
}

getData() {
  fetch('https://...com/demo/Feed/getFeedProducts.php')
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((json) => {
    this.setState({ data : json })
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
  });
}
```

In your render :

```
<FlatList data={this.state.data} renderItem={({item}) => (...)/>
```

P.S : juste you need to add a controler to check hte value of data before rendering it , because initialy it have , null value